# What is Element in mongoDB anyway?

Tags: mongodb

This mongoDB [document](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/) has 12 occurrences of **extra element**. Throughout its document it has clear definition for terms like *Field*, *document*, etc. but I've never seen one for *element*. 
My understanding is, it's the "thing" has a so-called *name*, so all **leaf** who has a name(label) such as *value* in key-value pair.

> Well, what exactly an **Element** is?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

'Elements' is a general term unless it's being used in a specific context, as it is with the [BsonIgnoreExtraElements] attribute. 'Elements' in this case would be whatever item is causing the exception in the deserialized BSON document.

More broadly, the word can refer to any of a handful of stored data, including the document size, field name, or value. It can also be used to describe many different parts of a database, including returned values or variables from arrays, and even the basic components of either noSQL or SQL databases, such as documents, collections, table, rows, etc.